# How do I install iTunes under Wine?

Tags: linux, itunes, fedora, wine

The standard procedure of switching to root and then entering `wine iTunesSetup.exe` doesn't  work.  I get a plethora of [error messages](https://files.getdropbox.com/u/389229/wine_iTunes_error.txt).  I am running Fedora 9.  I've done some Googling but haven't gotten very far.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the newest version of iTunes isn't compatible with wine.

Only iTunes 7.x actually works. [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about iTunes under Wine. But you have a few great alternatives on GNU/Linux.

I personally use **[Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/)** under Debian with my iPod, but you may also try:

- **[Rythmbox](http://www.gnome.org/projects/rhythmbox/)**
- **[Banshee](http://banshee-project.org/)**
- **[Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/)**